# AprilTags not detected when close to camera

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I can detect AprilTags that are "far" from the camera, ie. small on the image and even a little blur, but the detection fails when the tags are close to the camera and when the image is clean and neat, what is counter-intuitive.

Is this expected ?
How can I detect the tags at all scales ?

NB1: Interestingly, if I increase the "quad-decimate" param form default 1.0 to e.g. 16.0 (to reduce the image resolution), I can detect the "close" tag but not the "far" one (seems logical to not detect the small).

NB2: I use the VISP C++ lib directly, not the ROS apriltag packages, and images with 640x360 images

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408533/apriltags-not-detected-when-close-to-camera/) by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can get your anwser by reading through the  [paper](https://april.eecs.umich.edu/media/pdfs/olson2011tags.pdf), where the implementation is explained. Maybe one explanation is, that during the quad detection process only close enough lines are considered.

> Robustness to occlusions and
> segmentation errors is handled by
> adjusting the “close enough”
> threshold: by making the threshold
> large, significant gaps around the
> edges can be handled. Our threshold
> for “close enough” is twice the length
> of the line plus five additional
> pixels. This is a large threshold
> which leads to a low false negative
> rate, but also results in a high false
> positive rate.

That would explain why reducing the resolution helps detecting the closer tag.

---

Originally posted by [nils_iseke](https://answers.ros.org/users/120024/nils_iseke/) with karma: 76 on 2022-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0